# Live Boot CD Homeworking

Tags: system-installation

Apologies first off as I am very new to the whole Linux world so please be patient with me. I have outlined below what I want to do and want to know what is the best software and best way to do this.

We have approx 200 users who work from home and they currently have a dedicated HP thin client dispatched to them so they can connect to a cisco VPN and in turn connect to a Citrix Gateway where they then connect to a VDI.

What I would like below  :-)

We want to do away with having to dispatch users hardware for this and have them use their existing PC's, Laptops etc at home by booting off a USB/CD to enter a live environment where in turn they can do the same as above.

Basically this is a cost saving exercise as the logistics and upkeep of the hardware is pretty expensive. I am a quick learner and willing to try anything to get this working. If there is a dummies guide to generally doing this then please point me to it :-)

Your help on this matter would be greatly appreciated and I am excited as to what replies I get.

Thanks
Darren